# Ubuntu won't run after installation on a Chromebook

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm using Chromebook C720 and I installed Ubuntu, but when it restarts/reboots it enters into Chrome OS and not Ubuntu. How can I get Ubuntu working?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it alongside chrome os, it could be the boot loader is off.  I haven't attempted this with chrome os, but I do it all the time when I dual boot with ubuntu and windows.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Download and run boot repair disk, do the recommended repair, then restart your computer.

That solves most boot issues for me, but again do at your own risk.  I've never done it with chrome and I'm not very talented when it comes to boot, this is just a tool I found very useful.